# Converting epoch time to PST zone in hadoop/hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I want to convert the epoch time into pst time zone.
For example : 1482440069 when I convert to PST, I should get 2016-12-22

Now, when I try this I get proper answer

```
SELECT  from_utc_timestamp('1970-01-01 07:00:00', 'PST');
```

Also, When I try this, I get proper value

```
select from_unixtime(cast(1482440069 as bigint), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
o/p : 2016-12-22
```

But, When I try this query, I get NULL response

```
select from_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(cast(1482440069 as bigint), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'PST') -- Gives NULL response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
hive> select from_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(cast(1482440069 as bigint), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'PST');
OK
2016-12-22 04:54:29
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`SELECT  from_utc_timestamp(cast(from_unixtime('1970-01-01 07:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as bigint) + (time_zone value like -5 or -6 * 3600));`